# Django not able to find the installed app

Tags: python, django

I have copied the djnago app from here

https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload

I have put that folder in my root dir as fileupload.

But then go to .new/upload

i get the error no module named fileupload

But if go to python shell then i can `import fileupload` without any error

Comment: Have you added it in `INSTALLED_APPS` settings?

Comment: i have added that and my pythonpath has that path a sall other apps work in that folder

Comment: What do you mean by this statement "But then go to .new/upload"?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the app you are installing, perhaps you should try putting this in the URL

```
upload/new
```

instead of

```
new/upload
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the installed app in settungs.py file at INSTALLED_APP of the project then try to import it.